# Electron JS не работает дочерний(renderer) процесс

Tags: javascript, electron

Я новичок в JavaScript и фреймворке Electron, однако он кажется не таким уж сложным , но возникла очень неприятная проблема. Заключается она в том , что не работает дочерний процесс. Никаких ошибок или предупреждений , он просто не работает. Данный процесс отвечает за создание и функционирование контекстного меню . По типу File , Edit и так далее. Электрон по сути сам создает такое меню просто как шаблон , но оно без функций и просто не соответствует моим требованиям. Поэтому я начал создавать свое ,но писать все это в главном процессе , идея конечно рабочая , но потом читать код и выпускать его на гит , идея сомнительная.

И так

Вот код главного файла - main.js

```
//Constants for menu and requirements
const {app , BrowserWindow , Menu , dialog , ipcMain} = require('electron' , 'fs');





function createWindow() {

    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

   

    


    

    win.loadFile('index.html');
    
    //win.webContents.openDevTools();
    
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', ()=>{

    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {

        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate' , ()=> {

    if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {

        createWindow();
    }
});
```

Вот код дочернего процесса

actions.js

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const wnd = remote.getCurrentWindow();
const Template = [

    {
        label: "File",

        submenu: [

            {
                label: "Open"
            },

            {
                label: "Save"
            },

            {
                role: "close"
            }
        ]
    }
];


const menu = remote.buildFromTemplate(Template);
remote.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Comment: какая версия электрон? что пишет в консоли окна?

Comment: @nörbörnën , версия электрона - 15.1.2. В консоли окна ничего не пишется толком , кроме вот этого предупреждения Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
    Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
    this app to unnecessary security risks.

For more information and help, consult
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
This warning will not show up
once the app is packaged.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работал require добавьте contextIsolation в webPreferences.

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,

        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

Еще если я не ошибаюсь, то с 14го электрона remote является отдельным модулем его нужно отдельно импортировать и еще инициализировать.

```
const remoteMain = require("@electron/remote/main");
remoteMain.initialize();
```

Так же при открытии окна нужно "разрешать" использовать этому окну remote

```
function createWindow() {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
win.loadFile('index.html');

// Включаем его для окна
remoteMain.enable(win.webContents);
}
```

Итого:
main.js

```
//Constants for menu and requirements
const {app , BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
// Импортируем remote
const remoteMain = require("@electron/remote/main");
// Инициализируем
remoteMain.initialize();

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });
    win.loadFile('index.html');

    // Включаем его для окна
    remoteMain.enable(win.webContents);

    // win.webContents.openDevTools();
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', ()=>{
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
app.on('activate' , ()=> {
    if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

action.js

```
const electronRemote = require('@electron/remote');
const curWin = electronRemote.getCurrentWindow();
const Menu = electronRemote.Menu;

const Template = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            { label: "Open" },
            { label: "Save" },
            { role: "close" }
        ]
    }
];
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(Template);
curWin.setMenu(menu);  // Для определенного окна
// Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);  // Одинаковое для всех окно
```

Comment: Меню не появляется , никаких изменений нет , даже ошибок , просто обычное стандартное окно от electron